# How to generate the separate frontend from the gateway using JHipster?

Tags: microservices, jhipster

I am using JHipster's Gateway and UAA to work with microservices, to create the Gateway without the frontend I used the `jhipster -skip-client` command, however to create the separate front end of the Gateway I created a new folder and executed the command `jhipster --skip-server --auth oauth2 --db postgres --uaa-base-name uaa-server`.

The frontend generated with the command fails to authenticate because it seems that it gets lost in the addresses and tries to make a direct access to the Gateway service that is not configured in the system, how can I generate the frontend so that it is equal to the generated frontend along with Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.  First, when using UAA, the auth type should be `uaa` instead of `oauth2`.  Second, the `uaa-base-name` needs to match the base name in the generated UAA server, which by default is `uaa`.